# Slick Slider shows last element first

Tags: javascript, jquery, slick.js

I'm trying to find out whats wrong with the slick slider. When I set `centerMode: true;` it shows me the last element first instead the first element and If I switch `infinite: false;` it shows me the first slide empty. I need `centerMode: true` so I can show part of the next slide.

html:

```
        <div class="slider">
        <div class="col-12">1st</div>
        <div class="col-12">2nd</div>
        <div class="col-12">3rd</div>
        <div class="col-12">4th</div>
        </div>
```

JS:

```
        $(document).ready(function () {
              $('.slider').slick({
                centerMode: true,
                infinite: true,
                speed: 500,
                slidesToShow: 2,
            });
        });
```

**UPDATE:**

It seems that the following code (thanks to `pc_coder`) solves the initial problem but there is a new issue, I want also to have `dots: true;` as you can see [Codepen](https://codepen.io/gohan_360/pen/LYpmBay) it sets the 2nd dot to active `slick-active` first.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.slider').slick({
    dots: true,
    infinite: true,
    speed: 500,
    slide: 'div',
    centerMode: true,
    cssEase: 'linear',
    slidesToShow: 2,
    initialSlide:1
    });
});
```

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/gohan_360/pen/LYpmBay)

Thank you

Answer (score 4):

add `initialSlide:1,` then it will start from first

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.slider').slick({
        dots: true,
        autoplay: true,
        autoplaySpeed: 1000,
        infinite: true,
        speed: 500,
        slide: 'div',
        centerMode: true,
        cssEase: 'linear',
        slidesToShow: 2,
        initialSlide:1
    });
});
```

```css
.slider{
    width: 500px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.slider div{
  height:100px;
  background:gray;
  border:1px solid white;
  color:white
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.slick/1.3.15/slick.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.slick/1.3.15/slick.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
 <div class="slider">
        <div class="col-12">1st</div>
        <div class="col-12">2nd</div>
        <div class="col-12">3rd</div>
        <div class="col-12">4th</div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer the reason I need centerMode, I want to show part of the next slide.

Comment: It seems that your code solves the initial problem but there is a new issue, I want also to have `dots: true;` as you can see  [Codepen](https://codepen.io/gohan_360/pen/LYpmBay) it sets the 2nd dot to active slick-active first.

Comment: For slickslider normally if you choose first in center mode it always take last the left. So there is slickslider property. You can make that put your first slide to last and start then it will works as you expected.